# SARIMAX bug when modeling time series

Tags: python, model, time-series, jupyter-notebook

I am working on turning a previous time series analysis project in R into python using jupyter notebook and I am having trouble with the SARIMAX function and prediction. I have the following code:

```
def cvMSE(ts, order_totry = (0,0,0), seasorder_totry = (0,0,0), 
   d = 104, num_seas = 5, transformation = 'log'):
"""Computes MSE for a particular choice of transformation for the dataset 'ts'."""
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    return [l[i:(i + n)] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
len_fold = round(len(q1train_log)/num_seas)
MSE = ['NA' for i in range(num_seas)]; seas = seasorder_totry + (d,)
partitions = chunks(ts, len_fold)

for k in range(len(partitions)): 
    train_dt, test_dt = pd.concat([partitions[p] for p in range(len(partitions)) if p != k]), partitions[k]
    mod = SARIMAX(train_dt, order = order_totry, seasonal_order = seas, 
                  enforce_invertibility=False, enforce_stationarity=False).fit(disp=-1)
    fcst = mod.predict(start= len(train_dt), end= len(train_dt) + len_fold, dynamic=True)
    if transformation == 'log':
        MSE[k] = np.mean(np.array(fcst) - np.array(test_dt))**2 # reverses our previous log transformation
return mean(MSE)
```

cvMSE(q1train_log, order_totry = (0,0,1), seasorder_totry = (0,0,1))

I am trying to do cross validation on it, 5-fold with each fold being 104 data points. the length of the data set is 525. however whenever i run it i get this error:

```
ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
```

"Check mle_retvals", ConvergenceWarning)

and after a few lines of the error message the last line states:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? I have tried toggling with the parameters but I am not as familiar.